# What is a word for someone who loves to experiment?

Tags: single-word-requests

I have accidentally done an anglicism of a french word: "expérimentaliste", which I turned into *experimentalist*, before realising the word does not exist. I have looked up my issue, and found only a similar question on this forum asking what is a word for someone who loves to experience.
My question does not concern someone who loves to experience things, but someone who enjoys experimenting with things. I have found no other resources, so I'm asking here if such a word exists.

Comment: "Experimentalist" definitely is a valid word. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/experimentalist

Comment: @HotLicks Oh, I didn't realise. My autocorrect underlined the word and when I checked on vocabulary.com, it was not there. Well, thank you for then!

Comment: you might want to [easily check more than one dictionary](https://onelook.com/?w=experimentalist&ls=a)

Comment: @green_ideas - Or just Google `define experimentalist`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Experimentalist** is defined in the (paywalled) OED as:

> 1. One who devotes himself to experimental research in some branch of science; one who is skilled in performing experiments.
> 2. One who is fond of trying experiments, or who advocates new schemes.

The word is over 200 years old.

It is also listed in [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/experimentalist) and [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/experimentalist).

Comment: I'm confused then, the word is underlined red when I use it online and in microsoft word. In any case, thank you.

Comment: @FMB - Never trust the underlining demons.  They are there to warn you that something MIGHT be wrong, but are in no way a valid indication that something IS wrong.